# If $N$ is a $R$-submodule of $M$, then $\operatorname{End_{R}}(N)$ is subring of $\operatorname{End}_{R}(M)$?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $N$ a $R$ submodule of $M$, then $\operatorname{End}_{R}(N)$ is subring of $\operatorname{End}_{R}(M)$. Basically I just need to do is the subring test:

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Subring_Test

where (1), (2) and (3) seems easy to prove. But Im doubting if it always happens that $\operatorname{End}_{R}(N) \subset\operatorname{End}_{R}(M)$ as if I take some $f \in \operatorname{End}_{R}(N) $ how  I can extend this to  $f \in \operatorname{End}_{R}(M) $?? So is it true that $\operatorname{End}_{R}(N)$ is subring of $\operatorname{End}_{R}(M)$ for my hypothesis or there is a counterexample? If this is not true does anyone know something about necessity conditions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Obviously not.

Consider $R=M=\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ and $N=2\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$.

Then $End(N_R)$ is the field of two elements, and has characteristic $2$, and $End(M_R)\cong \mathbb Z/ 4\mathbb Z$ has characteristic $4$, so the former can't be a subring of the latter.

---

Another natural thing to investigate is if $N_R$ is a fully invariant submodule of $M_R$ (meaning $f:N\subseteq N$ for every $f\in End(M_R)$.  In that case, every endomorphism of $M$ restricts to an endomorphism of $N$, and you have a map from $End(M_R)\to End(N_R)$, of some sort, which I will let you investigate.

Comment: This way you are sending each $f \in End(M_{R})$ into $f$ restricted to $N$ I got it.This map is well defined, but I can  not show it is injective  or it is surjective. Still thinking how this help me see $End(N_{R}) \subset End(M_{R})$ :/ @rschwieb

Comment: @Cos the counterexample I gave is meant to make you *stop* thinking about it.

Comment: So you are saying nor even it happens that if $N$ is simple sumbmodule of $M_{R}$, then $End(N)$ subring of $End(M)$?? @rschwieb

Comment: @Cos It shows End(N) need not be a subring of End(M) do you follow the argument?